# Is there a name for this type of yoga/balance movement?

Tags: yoga, movements

This is kind of strange question, but I'm wondering if there's a specific name for the type of movement I'm describing (I'm not sure if it's a "real" yoga movement or what) - I have tried to search for this but can't come up with anything so I figured I'd try here.

Often when at yoga, I'll have my feet behind my body (say in downward dog, for example), and the teacher will tell us to move them forward (e.g. so we end up sitting on our rear ends with our legs out in front of us).  I realized I could support myself with my hands, and lift my legs off the ground, and move them (still off the ground) in front of me.  In other words, I'm basically rotating so my feet/legs/waist move through the space between my chest and the floor, and the only parts of my body that's touching the floor are my hands.

I hope that's descriptive enough.  My question is if there is a specific name for types of movements like this, because I really like the balance and strength that they require, and would like to learn more similar movements and get tips on them.  I guess in some ways they are similar to inversions but the only search results for that are actual headstands and stuff like that.

Thanks for any information you might be able to give...

Comment: I think it's called a sit up ,

Comment: No, not at all.  The only parts of my body touching the ground are my hands.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From what you're describing, it sounds like a ["Jump Through"](http://www.yogajournal.com/practice/765). A Jump Through involves starting in the [Downward Dog](http://www.pponline.co.uk/encyc/warming-up-the-downward-dog-yoga-exercise-1106) position and pivoting your body on your shoulders until you reach the [Staff](http://www.yogawiz.com/yoga-poses/seated-poses/staff-pose.html) position. Doing this transition in reverse is called a Jump Back. [Here's a YouTube video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mmxu4DI4qzQ) that has a pretty nice example of both transitions.

So, in order to perform this transition:

- Start in the Downward Dog position.
  [image]
- Propel your body forward and tuck yourself into a ball-like shape, engaging your abs and crossing your legs.
- Straighten you legs and body into the Staff position as you land again on your buttocks.
  [image]

Comment: I agree; this definitely sounds like what the OP is describing. These types of transitions are called "floating" in Ashtanga terminology.

Answer (score 1):

In Asthanga Yoga it is calleed "A vinyasa" (There are a few different versions)